# The button still disabled after login again into application

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have many buttons in a page, now I what want do is, every account can select one button, when they select that button, that button will be disabled and when account is logged out, open application again ,the button should be still disabled. If anyone know the answer, please kindly help me.

Thanks.

I am using android studio and my login and register using SQLite.

Comment: and every user can select one button only

Comment: add code please

Comment: which part of code? the button page code?

Comment: yes.. which affect to the enable and disable of button

Comment: setNeutralButton("Redeem", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                        button7.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                        button7.setEnabled(false);

Comment: You should enable it again once its Logout

Comment: and my activity is fragment

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what mean should enable it again once its logout?

Comment: I think when you log out your fragment is not going to destroy or you activity too. Are you using the same fragment for login and logout? Try to do this thing Whenever you login and come to this page where your "Redeem" button enable it button7.setEnable(true);

Comment: for login page is activity , logout i do like menu logout and the activity in that page is fragment

Answer (score 1):

You should use **Shared Preferences** in the application for storing button visibility value. When the button is clicked then give your preference some value and when logging out of the application simply clear that shared preference value so that button will not be disabled any more.

Put this code inside click listener of button

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences((MY_PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("value","buttondisabled");
editor.apply();
```

Put this code in the onCreate method of your activity

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String name = preferences.getString("value", "");
if (value.equals("buttondisabled")
{
 yourbutton.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE)
}
```

and when logging out of the application simply write these lines:

```
Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFS_NAME", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
```

Thats it :)

Answer (score 1):

When you click logout button, please save a variable to SharePreference:

```
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences("Name", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isLogout", true);
    editor.commit();
```

Now application will keep variable isLogout = true.
Next time when come to that screen, you just need to get this variable to check:

```
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    \\the true which is second parameter is default value that you want if isLogout variable is null
    if( prefs.getBoolean("isLogout", true)){
        button.disable
    };
```

Comment: 1st block inside on click button. Second block after findViewbyId(ur button)

Comment: second block, getDefaultSharedPreferences(this); the (this) come red error and disable also come out red error

Comment: this mean getActivity() if inside fragment. ActivityName.this if inside activity

Comment: my one is fragment, may i know i should write how?

Comment: fragment: replace this = getActivity()

Comment: how about disable?

Comment: i told u above, button.enableClick(false)